# How do you view eDrawing files on a web application?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, html

I'd like to create a feature to view eDrawing files like .eprt, .easm, or .step in a web application. There's already applications to view files like these for mobile apps, but that's not what I want.

ex: http://www.solidworks.com/sw/products/edrawings-mobile.htm

If there's a framework out there to help me do this, that'd be helpful as well.

Comment: do a google search.. have you tried there at least..?

Comment: Tried my best. StackOverflow was actually my last resort...

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I am considering converting to pdf'

Answer (score 0):

You could embed the object in your web page as per the following:

```
<OBJECT 
    align=middle 
    width="800"
    height="600"
    ID="EModelViewControl"
    CLASSID="CLSID:22945A69-1191-4DCF-9E6F-409BDE94D101">  
    <PARAM name="Filename" value= "E:\Test\Example.EASM"/>   
    <PARAM name="EnableFeatures" value="16385"/>
</OBJECT>
```

These links may provide more information:

- https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/66715
- https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/25769

**OR** you can download the [eDrawings Viewer](http://www.edrawingsviewer.com/) and save as .htm, which embeds the file into one large htm file.

Hope this helps someone out there!

Comment: can someone tell me what's the SDK that's been used here for the object to work and the .net framework version? I need what are the references that's been added from eDrawing.